# how can i count null values or non-null values with range of date using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

here's the first thing i thought about

```
SELECT * 
FROM   DATABASE..TABLE
WHERE  (FIELDNAME BETWEEN 'DATE' AND 'DATE') 
AND    (COUNT(FIELDNAME2) IS NULL)
```

i am new to sql

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please include some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [CountOfNull],
       SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [CountOfNotNull]
FROM DATABASE..TABLE WHERE FIELDNAME IS NULL OR (FIELDNAME BETWEEN 'DATE' AND 'DATE')
```

Comment: Surely in that scenario `CountOfNull` can't be anything other than 0?

Comment: Fieldname is Null or between 'DATE' and 'DATE'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whether you're asking for:

```
Select COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyDateField IS NULL
      OR (MyDateField BETWEEN 'StartDate' AND 'EndDate');
```

Which will get you a count of records where your date is either NULL or in the given range.

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [CountOfNull],
       SUM(CASE WHEN FIELDNAME IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [CountOfNotNull]
FROM DATABASE..TABLE
WHERE FIELDNAME IS NULL OR
      (FIELDNAME BETWEEN 'DATE' AND 'DATE')
```

Which will get you a count of records where the date is null, and a count of records where it falls in the given range.